# Mat-paginator is not floating to the right-end while scrolling the table on its x-axis in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

[image]

**Context:**

I have an Angular component with a table using Angular Material's mat-table and a paginator. The table displays data fetched from a data source, and the paginator is not floating to the right when I scroll horizontally.

**Code:**

```html
<!-- Your code here -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="table-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table id="ExampleMaterialTable" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="custom-approvalTable">
      <!-- ... (rest of your code) ... -->
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10, 20, 50, 100]" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageIndex]="currentPage"
      showFirstLastButtons (page)="handlePage($event)" [length]="totalSize"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz where the issue happens

Answer (score 0):

please do mat pagination static right side and scroll add only table

please visit this link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-scroll?file=main.ts